I don't understand what linearity means in definition of a distribution
Let's take 3 functions:

$f(x) = (x^2 + 1)^2$
$g(x) = \sin(x)$
$z(x) = \delta_0$

Neither of them are linear if using following definition of linearity:
$$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$
For example, $\delta_0(2) = 0$ but it also equal $\delta_0(0) + \delta_0(2)$ which isn't zero. So I clearly don't understand the definition of linear functional. What is the right definition that will say that all of those functions are linear functionals and therefore distributions?

You should provide the definition of distribution that you are working with.

Distributions don't act on $\mathbb R$, they act on some function space.

While distributions are in some sense generalizations of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, they are not linear as real functions. Instead, the generalization works as follows (see José Carlos Santos' answer as well): For any continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, we obtain a linear functional $\tilde f:\mathcal C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ on the space of test functions $\mathcal C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ defined by $\psi\mapsto \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\psi(x)\mathrm dx$. When we say that a normal function $f$ is a distribution, we really mean that $\tilde f$ is a distribution.
And there are other linear functionals which can't be obtained from a continuous function in this way. For instance, the $\delta$-distribution is the function mapping $\psi\mapsto\psi(0)$. This is a linear map, but there isn't actually a function $\delta$ which could define a fitting functional $\tilde \delta$. We just sometimes pretend that such a function exists in order to work in a familiar framework, and we call this pseudo function $\delta$. But the actual distribution is a linear functional on $\mathcal C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, not a function on $\mathbb R$.

Let $f$ be any continuous function and take $\psi\in\mathcal C_c^\infty(\Bbb R)$ (that is, $\psi$ is a class $\mathcal C^\infty$ function from $\Bbb R$ into itself with compact support). Then the integral $\int_\Bbb Rf(x)\psi(x)\,\mathrm dx$ makes sense and it is a real number. So, we can associate with $f$ the linear functional$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathcal C_c^\infty(\Bbb R)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\\psi&\mapsto&\int_\Bbb Rf(x)\psi(x)\,\mathrm dx.\end{array}\label{a}\tag1$$And then we identify $f$ with this linear functional. So, even if $f$ itself is not linear (and, in general, it is not) we identify it with the linear functional \eqref{a}.
